# SQL: Getting specific row values on a column after a join

Tags: sql, sqlite, inner-join

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
    "metaCAE"."family",
    "metaCAE"."name",
    COUNT(1) AS "count"
FROM
    "userHistoryProfessional"
INNER JOIN
    "company_metaCAE"
        ON (
            "company_metaCAE"."id_company" = "userHistoryProfessional"."id_company"
        )
INNER JOIN
    "metaCAE"
        ON (
            "metaCAE"."id" = "company_metaCAE"."id_metaCAE"
        )
WHERE
    "userHistoryProfessional"."dateUntil" IS NULL
GROUP BY
    "metaCAE"."family"
ORDER BY
    "count" DESC;
```

The schema for the metaCAE table is

```
id
level
family
name
```

Where several names belong to the same family, and only one name is the parent of that family, having the lowest level (1).

Example, excluding id column:

```
level family   name
1     A        Pork
2     A        Pork-Products
3     A        Pork-Products Incorporated
1     B        Cork
2     B        Cork-Products
3     B        Cork-Products Incorporated and Sons
3     B        Cork Incorporated
```

The problem is that I only want the name of the parent level (1) of each family to appear on my join, but company_metaCAE.id_metaCAE only references children level names from the metaCAE table (actual company names).

So, what I want to do is to get a result where I replace the children level names with the corresponding  parent level name. In my schema, that is the name that has the lowest level and the same family.

So instead of this result:

```
family count family-name
A      1     Pork-Products Incorporated
B      2     Cork Incorporated
```

I would want something like

```
family count family-name
A      1     Pork
B      2     Cork
```

Comment: did i get that right that company_metaCAE.id_metaCAE only contains children?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add another inner join to your query:

```
   SELECT
        "metaCAE"."family",
        parentMetaCAE."name",
        COUNT(1) AS "count"
    FROM
        "userHistoryProfessional"
    INNER JOIN
        "company_metaCAE"
            ON (
                "company_metaCAE"."id_company" = "userHistoryProfessional"."id_company"
            )
    INNER JOIN
        "metaCAE"
            ON (
                "metaCAE"."id" = "company_metaCAE"."id_metaCAE"
            )
    INNER JOIN                               ---- PARENT INNER JOIN
        (SELECT family, name 
         FROM metaCAE
         WHERE level = 1) parentMetaCAE
           ON (parentMetaCAE.family = metaCAE.family)
    WHERE
        "userHistoryProfessional"."dateUntil" IS NULL
    GROUP BY
        "metaCAE"."family"
    ORDER BY
        "count" DESC;
```

Comment: just had to change id=1 to level=1, but worked perfectly, thanks. =)